# Why are my R Plotly scatter dot sizes random and not what I specified?

Tags: r, plotly

Below is a small example of my code that shows the problem.

I want the generated dot sizes to be derived from the values in `offset`.
To get reasonable values, I calculate it before.
The values range from around 2 - 20.

However, the dot sizes in the plot are completely off.

Additionally, the dot sizes in the legend are not consistent.

```
library(plotly)

offset_plot_colors <- c('#845EC2', '#D65DB1', '#FF6F91', '#FF9671', '#FFC75F', '#F9F871')

df <- data.frame(
  insert_position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  experiment = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 
                 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102,
                 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103),
  sensor_position = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", 
                      "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", 
                      "s6", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", 
                      "s5", "s6", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"),
  offset = c( -0.10187856, -0.11539658, -0.01525474,  0.06469351, -0.13144734,  0.10990038
            , -0.11939423, -0.12415050, -0.01897634,  0.06963700, -0.12348225,  0.11077662
            ,  0.09999526, -0.11111048, -0.13619725, -0.03287019,  0.05424941, -0.12881697
            , -0.12830725,  0.09734471, -0.11105168, -0.12477904, -0.02409957,  0.06817639)
)

# calc size of dot
df$size <- abs(df$offset) * 150

offset_plot1 <- plot_ly(df, 
  x = ~experiment, y = ~insert_position, 
  color = ~sensor_position, 
  colors = offset_plot_colors,
  marker = list(size = ~size, opacity=1)
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    text = ~paste("Sensor:", sub(".*_", "", sensor_position), "<br>Offset:", round(df$offset, digits = 2), "<br>size:", size), 
    hoverinfo = "text"
  )

offset_plot1 <- offset_plot1 %>% layout(
  title = "Offset vs Insert Position vs Experiment",
  xaxis = list(title = "Experiment"),
  yaxis = list(title = "Insert Position"),
  legend = list(title = "Offset")
)

offset_plot1
```

[image: generated plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the size issue, I've made a few slight adjustments to your plotting routine.

##### Explanation of Changes

1. Added all of the data using `plotly::plot_ly` rather than using the `add_markers` call.
2. Added key names to the `offset_plot_colors` vector to ensure that the markers are colored correctly. This argument has to be passed in the `plot_ly` function, not the `add_markers` function, otherwise it won't work.
3. Updated the `layout` so that the x-axis tick step is now 1 (`dtick = 1`), and I made sure to include your legend title (`title = "Offset"` -> `title = list(text = "Offset")`).

##### Code

```r
offset_plot_colors <- c(
  "s1" = '#845EC2',
  "s2" = '#D65DB1',
  "s3" = '#FF6F91',
  "s4" = '#FF9671',
  "s5" = '#FFC75F',
  "s6" = '#F9F871'
)

offset_plot1 <-
  plotly::plot_ly(
    df,
    x = ~ experiment,
    y = ~ insert_position,
    color = ~ sensor_position,
    colors = offset_plot_colors,
    size = ~ size,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste(
      "Sensor:",
      sub(".*_", "", sensor_position),
      "<br>Offset:",
      round(df$offset, digits = 2),
      "<br>size:",
      size
    ),
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  ) %>%
  plotly::layout(
    title = "Offset vs Insert Position vs Experiment",
    xaxis = list(title = "Experiment", dtick = 1),
    yaxis = list(title = "Insert Position"),
    legend = list(title = list(text = "Offset"))
  )

offset_plot1
```

##### Image

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not really get it why, but it works.
I added
`,
    marker = list(
      opacity = 1
    )`
after marker = list to get rid of the opacity.

Comment: It is interesting that the max size of the dots is now considerably smaller. 
However, nothing works to increase the size of the biggest dots.
(sizemode, sizeref, different scaling for size values itself (I tried to use the log() of the value, this helps with the spread, but I would like the max size to be bigger)

Answer (score 0):

As the maximum dot size was smaller with Jacubs solution, I came up with this solution, just if someone else has the same problem.

```
offset_plot1 <-
    plot_ly(df,
        x = ~experiment, 
        y = ~insert_position, 
        color = ~sensor_position,
        colors = offset_plot_colors,
        type = "scatter", 
        mode = "markers",
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = ~paste(
            "Sensor:",
            sub(".*_", "", sensor_position),
            "<br>Offset:",
            round(offset, digits = 2),
            "<br>size:",
            size
        ),
        size = ~size, 
        marker = list(
            opacity = 1,
            #size = ~size, 
            sizemode = "diameter",
            sizeref = 2.5
        )
    ) %>%
    plotly::layout(
        title = "Offset vs Insert Position vs Experiment",
        xaxis = list(title = "Experiment", dtick = 1),
        yaxis = list(title = "Insert Position"),
        legend = list(title = list(text = "Offset"))
    )
```

Result
[image: plot]